# Elixir pattern matching maps

Tags: elixir

I am trying to pattern match a key value in a map and discard everything else.

```
identity = RedditOAuth2.get_identity(access_token)
# here is how i am getting the key "name" right now.
name = Map.get(identity, "name")
#----------------------------------------
# How would i do something like this
%{"name" => name | rest} = RedditOAuth2.get_identity(access_token)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have have multiple `=` in a single match.

```
%{"name" => name} = identity = RedditOAuth2.get_identity(access_token)
```

`identity` will have the entire map assigned to it and `name` will have whatever was in the `"name"` key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to discard everything else from the identity and are okay adding another function, you may be looking for [`Map.split/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#split/2).

```rb
{%{"name" => name}, identity} =
  access_token
  |> RedditOAuth2.get_identity()
  |> Map.split(["name"])
```